# passing prop to child component not updating the dom

Tags: vuejs2

I have following situation:
i have a form (child)component that has a input field.

```
//child component
<input type="text" placeholder="Field" v-model="rs.title"/>
```

and `rs` here is a prop passed down by `parent` component

I have a parent component in which i create many instance of this component like:

```
<form v-for="(row,index) in no_of_segments" :rs.sync="row"/>
```

i am doing this way because i also need to track field values of all form components.

so i have a array `no_of_segments` defined in parent component which contains values like this :

```
[{'field':val1},{'field':val2},...]
```

I pass objects in this array down to child component as `prop` so that each field can be rendered with its values:

But the problem is when i push a new item to `no_of_segments` in parent component, ***a new instance of `form` get created but without its values being rendered.***

Comment: This usually is a problem with reactivity. How do you push a new item to the no_of_segments array and how is no_of_segments initialized?

Comment: @Emptyless its sinitialized as     `no_of_segments: {title:' '}[] = [];` & pushing using `push` method& i am using vue2

Comment: @Emptyless also my prop was initialized as   @Prop() public rs: `{ field: string }={field:''};` but when i changed it to `@Prop() public rs: `{ field: string };` it worked but in console i get this error `26:18 Property 'rs' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`